# Child view controller's view is not shown in a container

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, containers, subview

I have a scene in the storyboard with a `Container View`. As you may suppose, I want its associated `UIViewController` to load there another `UIViewController` as a child view controller, and to show its view as a subview.

So, in the parent `UIViewController` I defined the properties:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyChildViewController *childController;
```

Then, in the `viewDidLoad` method of the parent, I do:

```
if (self.childController == nil) {
    self.childController = [[MyChildViewController alloc] init];
}

[self addChildViewController:self.childController];
self.childController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.containerView.frame.size.width, self.containerView.frame.size.height);
[self.containerView addSubview:self.childController.view];
[self.childController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Both `self.childController.view` and `self.containerView` are not `nil`, but `self.childController.view` is not displayed when I run the app... What can I be missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally noticed what I was overlooking... since I also created a scene in the storyboard for `MyChildViewController`, I needed to instantiate it from there.

Comment: where did you instantiate?